# Drupal 7:User information not saving when edited by allowed users

Tags: drupal-7

I'm currently developping a new website for an artists organization. The administrator role is allowed to create accounts and some other node content, the created accounts have the same default role called "artisan". Administrators are Artisans as well. Artisans can create and edit their own content. Both administrators and artisans should be able to edit user profile (all for admin, only their own for artisan). The fact is admin can create a user but nobody (except user1) can save user profile after edit (but it works great for other nodes). Permissions have been scanned multiple times. I have been searching everywhere with no success, what am I missing ? I made very few changes, the only related code I wrote is the following :

```
 <?php
function canardesign_system_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
global $user;
    switch ($form_id){
    case 'oeuvre_node_form':
            $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'canardesign_system_oeuvre_redirect';
                if (in_array('artisan', array_values($user->roles))){
                    $form['field_auteur']['#type']= 'hidden';
                    $form['field_auteur']['und']['#default_value']= $user->uid;
                }
        break;
    case 'user_profile_form':
    if (in_array('artisan', array_values($user->roles))){
            $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'canardesign_system_user_profile_form_submit';
        }
        break;
    }
}
function canardesign_system_oeuvre_redirect($form, &$form_state) {
    $type=$form['#node']->type;
    if(isset($type))
    {
         $node = node_load($form_state['nid']);
        $uid=field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_auteur')[0]['target_id'];
        $form_state['redirect'] = 'oeuvres/'.$uid;
    }
  }
function canardesign_system_user_profile_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_goto('artisans');
}
/*default role when administrator (who is artisan as well) creates an account*/
function canardesign_system_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
    global $user;
    if (in_array('artisan', array_values($user->roles))){
      $account->role = 'artisan';
  }
}
?>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of your issue, but calling `drupal_goto()` inside a submit hook is definitely problematic. It essentially shorts out the handling of the form.

This may be causing the issue by preventing other necessary code from executing.

You should instead set the `redirect` key of `$form_state` to the destination you would like the user to end up on.

Once the form handling is complete, Drupal will send the user there.

```
function canardesign_system_user_profile_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'artisans';
}
```

Comment: You are right, once I removed drupal_goto() the profile saved as expected. Nevertheless, no redirection occured. So I ended up with creating a new rule, which brought the benefit to add fine tuned conditions and reactions without any coding. Thank you !